# Dart mirrors issue. getField

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying use mirrors, but I have error in some simple code.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
// -----------------
class TestUser extends Object{
  String name = 'aaa';
  String status = 'bbb';
  String position = 'ccc';
  int age = 20;
}

var mapVal = new TestUser();
InstanceMirror mirror = reflect(mapVal);

var futureValue = mirror.getField('age');
futureValue.then((imValue) => print("Field: age = ${imValue.reflectee}"));
```

Result:

```
Unhandled exception:
Class 'String' has no instance getter '_name@0x1aab143'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '_name@0x1aab143'
Receiver: "age"
Arguments: []
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      Symbol.getName (dart:_collection-dev/symbol.dart:64)
#2      _n (dart:mirrors-patch/mirrors_impl.dart:59)
#3      _LocalObjectMirror.getField (dart:mirrors-patch/mirrors_impl.dart:254)
#4      main (file:///C:/Users/Less/IdeaProjects/testDart/console/template.dart:67:36)
#5      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:216)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115)
```

What it means? I have no idea. Why it takes '_name@0x1aab143' from String? Black magic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
var mapVal = new TestUser();
InstanceMirror mirror = reflect(mapVal);
// getField() expects an instance of Symbol, not String
var futureValue = mirror.getField(new Symbol("age"));
// getField() returns an InstanceMirror, not a Future<InstanceMirror>
print("Field: age = ${futureValue.reflectee}");
```

Could it be that you updated your SDK, but not your Editor? The current Editor with the current SDK shows all of that as a warning, making troubleshooting this code rather trivial.

Comment: thanks! your answer was more complete )
I was fighting with eclipse editor, but now I'm trying use IDEA.
No one from them is ideal, as I see.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in Dart is async ;-)

```dart
// mirror.getField('age');
InstanceMirror im = mirror.getField(#age); // needs a symbol

// futureValue.then((imVa
print("Field: age = ${im.reflectee}")); // getField doesn't return a future
```

Comment: ooh, that #symbols... :)

Comment: Didn't you get a warning in DartEditor? Mine showed a yellow line when I pasted your code.

Comment: I use IDEA plugin at last several weeks. DartEditor doing some strange, like running dart.exe with 40% CPU all time.

Comment: Probably the analyzer which produces the warnings ;-)

Comment: Maybe. It should be very strong analyzer :)

Comment: @SergioLesnik I am no sure. I think it would be slow analyzer because some algorithms and structures in this second version of analyzer again not so efficient. Draw conclusions after reading the issues on dartbug.com. Also you may compare it performance and performance (and quality) of TypeScript analyzer in Visual Studio.